# Trying to understand why page sizes are a power of 2?

Tags: binary, paging, bit-manipulation

I read this:

> Recall that paging is implemented by
>   breaking up an address into a page and
>   offset number. It is most efficient to
>   break the address into X page bits and
>   Y offset bits, rather than perform
>   arithmetic on the address to calculate
>   the page number and offset. Because
>   each bit position represents a power
>   of 2, splitting an address between
>   bits results in a page size that is a
>   power of 2.

I don't quite understand this answer, can anyone give a simpler explanation?

Comment: Needs more context. Can you provide the question which precedes the answer too?

Comment: I'm *almost* sure today machines perform bit manipulation and integer operations at the same speed (discarding pipelining, cache hits, MMX, SSE and so)

Comment: @ATorras A lot of these address computations take place in dedicated hardware, so using general division and remainder would slow things down and make the circuitry more complex, without any real benefit.

Answer (score 18):

If you are converting a (linear) address to page:offset, you want to divide the address by the page size and take the integer answer as the page, and the reminder as the offset.

This is done using integer division and modulus (MOD, "%") operators in your programming language.

A computer represents an address as a number, stored as binary bits.

Here's an example address: 12 is 1100 in binary.

If the page size is 3, then we'd need to calculate 12/3 and 12%3 to find the page and offset (4:0 respectively).

However, if the page size is 4 (a power of 2), then 4 in binary is 100, and integer division and modulus can be computed using special 'shortcuts': you can strip the last two binary digits to divide, and you can keep only the last two binary digits for modulus.  So:

`12/4 == 12>>2` (shifting to remove the last two digits)

`12%4 == 12&(4-1)` (4-1=3 is binary 11, and the '&' (AND) operator only keeps those)

Answer (score 3):

Working with powers of two leads to more efficient hardware so that's what hardware designers do.  Consider a cpu with a 32-bit address, and an n-bit page number:

```
+----------------------+--------------------+
| page number (n bits) | byte offset (32-n) |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

This address is sent to the virtual memory unit, which directly separates the page number and byte offset without any arithmetic operations at all.  Ie, it treats the 32-bit value as an array of bits, and has (more or less) a wire running directly to each bit.  This allows the memory hardware to extract the page number and byte offset in parallel, without performing any arithmetic operations.

At the same time, this approach requires splitting on a bit boundary, which leads directly to power-of-2 page sizes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have *n* binary digits at your disposal, then you can encode 2<sup>n</sup> different values.

Given an address, your description states some bits will be used for the page, and some for the offset. As you're using a whole number of binary bits for the for offset Y, then the page size is naturally a power of 2, specifically 2<sup>Y</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

Because the representation of the data. The page offset sets the size of the page, and since the data is represented in binary, you will have a number n of bits to define the offset, so you will have pages with a size of 2^n.

Let's suppose you have an address like this 10011001, and you split it in 1001:1001 for page:offset. Since you have 4 bits to define the offset, your page's size is 2⁴.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not exact power of 2 then some memory address will be invalid. eg if the page size is 5 byte then to distinguish each byte we need 3 bit in the offset part of the address. Because using 2 bit only 4 byte can be addressed. But using 3 bit offset for 5 byte page keep two address unused. thats why page size should be .......

Answer (score 0):

since all addresses are in binary and are divided into f and d, f=frame no, d=offset. due to be the size in power of 2 a human no need to go for huge mathematical calculation, just by watching the address bits you can identify the f and d. If page size was 2^n the in physical address last n bits represents the offset and remaining bits represent page numbers.
Hopefully this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I didn't get was *how* the page sizes are a power of 2. I found out afterwards:

At the smallest level, the page is 1 bit (0 or 1) and the offset is 1 bit (0 or 1). Combining these together, the page size would be 2 x 2 (or 2^2), because of the number of bits they both have (2 each, so 2 x 2).

Now if the page/offset were larger, then it would be n x n -- n being the number of bits they both have.

Answer (score 0):

The page no. is always in the power of 2 as (2^n).
There are several reasons:
1.The memory address is also in 2^n so it will be more easy to move a page.
2.There are two bits which represent the page:
  a.Page no.         b.Offset no
  So,This is also the reason.
3.Memory is in quantised form like charge(q).